# Tinymec4 file manager error : There is an error! The root folder not exist

Tags: php, symfony, tinymce-4, file-manager

I am using file manager plugin (tinymce) to upload image. however i am able to upload image to particular folder but in image listing it is giving me error: **There is an error! The root folder not exist.** 
the path where i kept my file manager plugin is -

```
\web\bundles\stfalcontinymce\vendor\tinymce\plugins\filemanager
```

path for my upload folder is -

```
 web\tinymceuploads
```

So i am passing parameter in config.php of file manager is like -

```
 $base_url="http://localhost/example/web/app_dev.php/web"; //url base of site if you want only relative url leave empty
    $upload_dir = '/tinymceuploads/'; // path from base_url to upload base dir
    $current_path = '/../../../tinymceuploads/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder
```

But in image listing after clicking on upload button I am getting the error :
**There is an error! The root folder not exist.**  Please help me as soon as possible. it almost ate my head.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.Assume your tinymce folder located in http://localhost/projectname/tinymce/

2.Create folder images under tinymce eg: tinymce/images

3.Go to the folder location tinymce/plugins/filemanager/config.php

4.Go to the line near 15 to 20-- it will be look like this

base_url="http://localhost/projectname/";

$upload_dir = 'tinymce/images/';

$current_path = '../../images/';

5.Add this line

**$root='/tinymce/';**  or **$root='../tinymce/';**

Save and Run the project.

Hope it works....

Answer (score 0):

Assume Your directory look like this:

base_url="http://localhost/projectname/"; // base directory

|

|________ Working directory // you are now working in this

|

|________ tinymce directory

**Wrong configuration:**

```
base_url="http://localhost/projectname/";

$upload_dir = 'http://localhost/projectname/tinymce/images/';

$root='http://localhost/projectname/tinymce';
```

**Right Configuration:**

```
base_url="http://localhost/projectname/";

$upload_dir = '../tinymce/images/'; // from working folder to tinymce/images

$current_path = '../../images/';  // tinymce/plugins/filemanager to  path tinymce/images

$root='../tinymce/';
```

Your upload and root directory difference is **/images** alone

it works for me..

Answer (score 0):

please adjust your coding php like this

```
$root = rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'/'); // don't touch this configuration

//**********************
//Path configuration
//**********************
// In this configuration the folder tree is
// root
//   |- tinymce
//   |    |- source <- upload folder
//   |    |- js
//   |    |   |- tinymce
//   |    |   |    |- plugins
//   |    |   |    |-   |- filemanager
//   |    |   |    |-   |-      |- thumbs <- folder of thumbs [must have the write permission]

$base_url="http://localhost"; //url base of site if you want only relative url leave empty
$upload_dir = '/sik/assets/tinymce/source/'; // path from base_url to upload base dir
$current_path = '../../../../source'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder

$MaxSizeUpload=100; //Mb
```